# Adding Images side-by-side

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2010, microsoft-word-2007

I have three images of unequal size. I want to add them side by side horizontally in MS Word 2007/2010.

Currently when I manually add them through Insert -> Picture then they are added without proper spacing between them. Also since I have to manually resize them I am unable to resize them exactly to same size. So it is looking very bad with unequal size images with improper alignment.

Is there a method by which I can add images properly?

Comment: Do they have the same aspect ratio?

Comment: no, but I want to maintain only the same height, if width varies then its fine.

Comment: I can manually adjust the height of each image through format tab, but how can I align all 3 images horizontally with proper alignment & spacing?

Answer (score 3):

1) Turn on `Show/Hide`

2) Hit `Enter` enough times to create space

3) Click in front of one of these new lines, and then insert your first image.  Do the one on the right to make things easier.

4) Double click your image, and in the ribbon find `text wrapping` and choose the `In front of text` option.  Others may work... this is just the one I always use.

5) Click on the image and holding down your click, drag the image where desired.

6) Repeat 3-5 for the other two images.

7) Once you arrange your three images, you can judge if you need to resize one or more images.  When doing this, keep your aspect ratio by only using the corner pick boxes when resizing your image, and don't touch the side pick boxes.  If one is not horizontally aligned once resized, you can simply grab and move as needed to align.

8) Turn off `Show/Hide` (optional)

Answer (score 0):

You  can use a broad-less table with three columns and and one row, then you can size the table the way you want and past your pictures inside the cells, also, if you like, you may add captions on the next row (add new row below), bellow each of the figures. I hope with this you would get more control on sizing.